# Cochrane-Orcutt Prediction in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to predict specific values after using a cochrane-orcutt adjustment.  My issue is that using predict() or predict.orcutt(), is only returning the predicted values using the original data used to build the model.  The example below is not my data, but it can be used to replicate the problem.

```
# Values used to build model
build_model = mtcars[1:22,]

# Input values for future predictions
predict_values = mtcars[23:32,]

# Linear Model
fit = lm(mpg~cyl, build_model)

# Cochrane.Orcutt correction
coch_class = cochrane.orcutt(fit)

# Use Predict Function 
predict.orcutt(coch_class, newdata = predict_values$cyl)
```

[,1]
Mazda RX4           20.46226
Mazda RX4 Wag       20.46226
Datsun 710          26.01009
Hornet 4 Drive      20.46226
Hornet Sportabout   14.91443
Valiant             20.46226
Duster 360          14.91443
Merc 240D           26.01009
Merc 230            26.01009
Merc 280            20.46226
Merc 280C           20.46226
Merc 450SE          14.91443
Merc 450SL          14.91443
Merc 450SLC         14.91443
Cadillac Fleetwood  14.91443
Lincoln Continental 14.91443
Chrysler Imperial   14.91443
Fiat 128            26.01009
Honda Civic         26.01009
Toyota Corolla      26.01009
Toyota Corona       26.01009
Dodge Challenger    14.91443

Comment: It doesn't work correctly as a data.frame either (for this example or my original data).

Answer (score 1):

The `orcutt` library doesn't seem to support prediction with new data. The source for the `predict.orcutt` function just returns the fitted values. It ignores any parameters.

```
orcutt:::predict.orcutt
# function (object, ...) 
# {
#     return(object$fitted.values)
# }
```

Perhaps contact the authors of the package to see if they derived a method to make predictions after the adjustment.